# How to remove static keyword from the url?

Tags: angular, flask

I have a flask(backend)-angular(frontend) application. Currently, I am compiling the angular application using the following command

```
ng build --configuration production --base-href ""
```

Compiled files are stored in the "static" in the flask directory. Below is the layout

```
flask/
    -web_ui/
        -src/
            -static/
            -web_app.py
            -models.py
            -db_manage.py
```

After running the flask application using `flask run`, the problem is that the URL in the web browser looks like this

```
http://localhost:5000/static/dashboard
http://localhost:5000/static/login
http://localhost:5000/static/profile
http://localhost:5000/static/editprofile
```

. How do I get rid of the `static` keyword in the URL?

In my flask webb_app.py file, I have this one-line to point to static folder

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static', template_folder='static')
```

I want my URL to look like this `http://localhost:5000/dashboard`

The only change I have made is in the angular.json file in the frontend to compile and directly store in the `static` folder in the backend which I have marked with `#<---`

```
architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "/Users/sam/workspace/ws/flask_backend/web_ui/src/static", #<---
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/custom-theme.scss",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "src/assets/js/main.js",
          "node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.min.js"
        ]
      },
```

Comment: You haven't shared any code.

Comment: @TheTridentGuysupportsUkraine just added the config. please do let me know if I need to add anything else. The project code is too long to be posted here so i would be happy to post any snippet needed.

Answer (score 0):

try

"options": {
"baseHref": ""

}

Comment: tried that, makes no difference.

Comment: "options": { "baseHref": "dashboard"

}


have you tried like that?

Comment: i tried that and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the `static` URL prefix, you can set the `static_url_path` attribute to an empty string.

```py
app = Flask(__name__, 
    # ...
    static_url_path = '',
)
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. Instead, it gives me 404 error for all the assets.